# Solr range query for string field

Tags: solr, range, trie

There are trie fields for efficient numeric range query.
what about string? Why is there no TrieString?

Could I just use solr.StrField type for efficient string range query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add at the end of the url **q=somefield:[10   TO   200]**
For string range looks like is something like **stringfield: [a* TO z]** Have a look [solr querys](http://web.archive.org/web/20170510071443/https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)

Comment: Thanks. Can u explain why there is no TrieField for string type?

Comment: As they say in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr. TrieFields are are only for numerical fields. I think you should be using StrField or TextField

Comment: What I would possibly suggest is to add filters for better range search https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/About+Filters